# django 1.3 wsgi input error using django-page-cms 1.4

Tags: python, django, windows-xp

Im trying to upgrade an old project made using django 1.2 / django-page-cms 1.2 to django 1.3 / django-page-cms 1.4

Everything works fine until I try to edit/add a page. That's when I receive the following error:

```
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    'wsgi.input'
Exception Location:     C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py in __init__, line 138
Python Executable:  C:\Python26\python.exe
Python Version:     2.6.6
```

I've been through documentation and I still don't fully understand why I am receiving this error. Can somebody explain to me what's going on and most importantly how to fix it. Could it possibly be tied to an issue elsewhere in the project?

Help much appreciated. cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related specifically to the latest page cms when used with the latest version of django. It was fixed back in nov 2010.

the details and fix can be found here:

https://github.com/batiste/django-page-cms/issues/closed/#issue/14